# Выбрать периоды из массива

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

```
$array = [
    ['user_id' => 57, 'phone_code' => 104, 'date' => '2017-06-07 07:49:52'],
    ['user_id' => 43, 'phone_code' => 104, 'date' => '2017-06-07 08:57:41'],
    ['user_id' => 72, 'phone_code' => 104, 'date' => '2017-06-07 09:49:38'],
    ['user_id' => 57, 'phone_code' => 104, 'date' => '2017-06-07 11:08:34'],
    ['user_id' => 25, 'phone_code' => 104, 'date' => '2017-06-07 12:49:38'],
];
```

Нужно получить интервалы заходов юзера 57, а он считается от его первого входа, до авторизации другого юзера. Судя по массиву он входил 2 раза: с 7:49 по 8:57 и с 11:08 по 12:49

Как сделать красиво ? C учетом того что данных очень много)

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `phone_code` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1889 ;

INSERT INTO `user_log` (`id`, `user_id`, `phone_code`, `date`) VALUES
(1853, 57, 104, '2017-06-07 07:49:52'),
(1863, 43, 104, '2017-06-07 08:57:41'),
(1866, 72, 104, '2017-06-07 09:49:38'),
(1867, 57, 104, '2017-06-07 11:08:34'),
(1868, 25, 104, '2017-06-07 12:49:38');
```

Мое решение:

```
$user_id = 57;
$phone_code = 104;

$temp = [];

for($i=0; $i<=count($array); $i++){

    if($user_id == $array[$i]['user_id']){

       $temp[]=$i;    
       $start[] = $array[$i]['date'];
    }
}

foreach($temp as $k){

    if(!empty($array[$k+1]['user_id'])){
        if($array[$k+1]['user_id'] !=$user_id)
            $period[] = $array[$k+1]['date'];
    }
}
print_r($start);
print_r($period);
```

Comment: Вам нужно их получить именно так? `с 7:49 по 8:57 и с 11:08 по 12:49` и расчет общего времени захода?

Comment: Не совсем. Мне нужно получить все интервалы входа для заданного user_id. Т.е он вошел с кодом 104 и его период должен быть до того как другой юзер вошел с кодом 104 (его автоматом разлогинивает).

В данном примере с 57 юзером на выходе мне нужно:

с 7:49 по 8:57 и с 11:08 по 12:49  --- эти интервалы. 

Сижу голову ломаю как сделать красиво... Но на код 104 можно внимания не обращать, главное получить периоды его залогинивания.

Comment: Понятно то есть тебе по `user_id` надо подмассив интервалов?

Comment: Да от даты авторизации user_id до даты авторизации другого user_id - это и будет период.

Comment: ok сейчас попробую что то придумать

Comment: у меня последний вопрос, вы откуда берете этот массив? из базы? как оно формируется?

Comment: Да, код беру из базы, структура таблиц = ключи массива.

Comment: а может сразу взять оттуда то что вам нужно? а не брать все и во второй раз пройтись по нему для выборки нужного подмассива? обновите вопрос и дайте структуру таблицы если можно?

Comment: Обновил пост...

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример ответа на ваш вопрос с помощю `php`

```
$user_id = 57;
$array = [
    ['user_id' => 57, 'phone_code' => 104, 'date' => '2017-06-07 07:49:52'],
    ['user_id' => 43, 'phone_code' => 104, 'date' => '2017-06-07 08:57:41'],
    ['user_id' => 72, 'phone_code' => 104, 'date' => '2017-06-07 09:49:38'],
    ['user_id' => 57, 'phone_code' => 104, 'date' => '2017-06-07 11:08:34'],
    ['user_id' => 25, 'phone_code' => 104, 'date' => '2017-06-07 12:49:38'],
];

for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){

    if($array[$i]['user_id'] == $user_id){
        $phone_code = $array[$i]['phone_code'];
        break;
    }

}
$user_array = [];
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){

    if($array[$i]['phone_code'] == $phone_code && $array[$i]['user_id'] == $user_id && $array[$i+1]['user_id'] != $user_id){
        $user_array[$i]['date'] = $array[$i]['date'].' - '.$array[$i+1]['date'];
    }

}
print_r($user_array);
```

Но это не вариант, если у вас строки в таблице достигнут тысяч.

Для этого надо`SQL` запросом вывести только нужные строки.

Вот если тебе не составит труда создать вот такую таблицу то у тебя не будет проблем с выводом нужных строк.

```
CREATE TABLE `user_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prev_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `phone_code` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `user_log` (`id`, `user_id`, `prev_user_id`, `phone_code`, `date`) VALUES
(1853, 57, 52, 104, '2017-06-07 07:49:52'),
(1863, 43, 57, 104, '2017-06-07 08:57:41'),
(1866, 72, 43, 104, '2017-06-07 09:49:38'),
(1867, 57, 72, 104, '2017-06-07 11:08:34'),
(1868, 25, 57, 104, '2017-06-07 12:49:38');
```

И тут уже совсем простой запрос даст тебе то что нужно.

```
SELECT * FROM `user_log` WHERE `user_id` = 57 OR `prev_user_id` = 57;
```

И на последок для того что бы на больших количествах строк у тебя запрос не медлил можешь поставить на колонках `user_id` и `prev_user_id`индексы.